# pandas to_sql incorrect column name error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
data.to_sql('sample_table',mysql_engine, if_exists= 'replace', index = False)
```

When I run the above line, I get the error:

[image: error_message]

Why am I getting this? I am trying to write `data` to a mysql_db.

Comment: Can you post the full error message and stack trace?

Comment: I have editied the post and added the snapshot link.

Comment: In the future please include the full error message as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data has a column `'Point_of_reference '` with a trailing space at the end that makes the name invalid.

To fix it, remove all trailing and leading whitespace from your column names:

```
data.columns = data.columns.str.strip()
```

Comment: Thanks Ian and sorry for posting the question improperly, have not used much of stack overflow, but thanks for the help.